# Create a link from a div - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes

Currently I have a text link within the div that links correctly `<%= link_to 'Show', profile %>`. I have read that the below is the proper way to turn a div into a link

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div>Hey!</div>
<% end %>
```

Though when I apply that to my block it gives me a `undefined local variable or method 'profile'`

```
 <%= link_to profile do %>
  <div id="profiles" class="transitions-enabled">
   <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
   <div class="box panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <%= image_tag profile.image.url(:medium) %>
     <%= profile.artist %><br/>  
     <%= link_to 'Show', profile %>
    </div>
   </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

My original block without the attempt at linking:

```
<div id="profiles" class="transitions-enabled">
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <div class="box panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <%= image_tag profile.image.url(:medium) %>
     <%= profile.artist %><br/>  
     <%= link_to 'Show', profile %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :id]

# GET /profiles
# GET /profiles.json
def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
end

# GET /profiles/1
# GET /profiles/1.json
def show
end

# GET /profiles/new
def new
  @profile = Profile.new
end
#...
```

Comment: what is the html you're trying to output - if you put that in the q it'll be easy to give you the rails code to do what you want... but what do you want the output html to look like?  just an example...

Comment: @RichardJordan have a grid and just want each "profile" to be clickable -> http://cl.ly/image/3I1F2e3r0f08

Comment: your example above, though, has links inside links - so i'm a bit confused as to what you're hoping to come out of it - so if you can just put the basic html structure you're looking to output i can show you the rails code to efficiently do that

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is problematic in many ways - you have links inside links.  I'm not exactly sure what you're looking to output from this - but basically you need the

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div>Hey!</div>
<% end %>
```

behavior to replace where you have `<%= link_to 'Show', profile %>`

Something along the lines of:

```
<div id="profiles" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= image_tag profile.image.url(:medium) %>
        <%= profile.artist %><br/>

        <%= link_to profile do %>
          <div>
            fancy pants stuff here
          </div>
        <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If you can give me some guidance on what you want in the div I can post you some code to achieve that, I'm just not clear on what you are looking for exactly.

Another example could be (if you wanted more of the pieces to fall inside that `<div></div>`:

```
<div id="profiles" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <%= link_to profile do %>
          <div>
            <%= image_tag profile.image.url(:medium) %>
            <%= profile.artist %><br/>  
            ... more fancy pants stuff here ...
          </div>
        <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```